# Problems updating Kubuntu 20.04.02 Focal Fossa - Many error messages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, kubuntu

I have a problem updating my system. For some reason error messages are being displayed in Spanish even though I don't use it.

This is the error message what I got in terminal

```
E: El repositorio «cdrom://Kubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1) focal Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just delete the CDROM entry (ie. it refers to your installation media), see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Discover in preferences and uncheck the source: cdrom: // Ubuntu 20.04.2.0

Comment: Sorry I don't ubuntu software tab, I am using Kubuntu. I looked for some articles to know how to remove this cd-rom but none has been useful. Any suggetion?

Comment: Sorry. Is with Discover app

Comment: Carlos Dagorret thank you so much you are a genius!!!!. You have been so helpful and kind to me. I don't have word to express myself and I am really thanking to you.